# convexity of function built from piecewise linear convex function?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $B(x):[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ be piecewise linear increasing convex function with $B(0)=0$ and $B(1)=1$. (Think of the power of the neyman-persron test).
Let $E(x)=-log(B(1-e^{-x}))$ a logaritmic scaled version of $B(x)$ in both dimentions.

I need $E(x)$ to be convex. I also get this from simulations.

I derive as if there are no problems (i.e. between jumps of the pieces in $B$):
Define for simplicity $F(x)=B(1-e^{-x})$ so $E(x)=-log(F(x))$.

$E'(x) = -\frac{F'(x)}{F(x)}$

$E''(x) =  {\left( {\frac{{F'\left( R \right)}}{{F\left( R \right)}}} \right)^2} - \frac{{F''\left( R \right)}}{{F\left( R \right)}}$

Also using direct derivative of $F'(x)$ we can get:
$F''(x)=B''(1-e^{-x})e^{-2x}-F'(x)$

and substiute back:

$E''(x) = {\left( {E'\left( R \right)} \right)^2} - E'\left( R \right) - \frac{{B''\left( {1 - {e^{ - R}}} \right)}}{{F\left( R \right)}}{\left( {{e^{ - R}}} \right)^2}$

now, $B$ is piecewise linear so $B''(x)$ is zero "almost" everywhere and the rest is positive as $E$ is decresing.

How do I handle the jump points? I didn't use yet the convexity of $B$ and I think this should be in the jump point,

Any ideas?

Comment: You're going to have to use more information about $B(x)$ than you're giving us. Standard convex composition rules tell us that if $B$ were *concave*, then all is well: you would have the composition of a convex, decreasing function ($-\log$) with a concave, increasing function ($B$) with a concave function ($1-e^{-x}$), and this is convex. Alas, because $B$ is convex, the simple composition rules do not apply for you.

Comment: That's the reason why everything "works" when there are no jumps: between jumps, you have a linear increasing function, which is both convex and concave. Unfortunately, the jumps (or more precisely, how the slope changes from jump to jump) that is going to be critical.

Comment: The function $B(x)$ is convex overall and not just in the jumps. What other codition should I look for? How to handle jumps generally?

Comment: I do not have an answer for you. My point is that if B were concave, the jumps would be otherwise irrelevant. Since B is convex, I do not think I there is a useful condition to offer, and the jumps are precisely what matters the most. Perhaps the closest thing to my experience is geometric programming. From that context, what you want is for $G(z)=1/B(1-z)$ to be what we would call *log-log-convex*. But that just means $\log G(e^x)$ is convex, which is precisely what you want to prove. So as I said, not too useful here.

Comment: Perhaps what you should do is step back a couple of steps. You say you "need" E to be convex. Well, why? Do you intend to use this in some sort of optimization model? Do you intend to prove something else that depends on its convexity? Perhaps there is a elegant way through this impass, but it starts one or two steps back. And perhaps any questions you ask should be starting there, instead of here.